# Using getpixel in loop

Tags: python, pyautogui, rpa

Value check stays the same no matter what color does it get. It should give me RGB value of exact pixel every second

I tried doing it in recursion, simplified it, tested on multiple objects, result stays the same.

```
im = pg.screenshot()
import time

while True:
        check=im.getpixel((216, 169))
        time.sleep(1)
        print(check)
```

I expected the dynamically changing output depending on the color of pixel (216, 169). Currently I receive the same RGB value every second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking the screenshot once and then re-checking it over and over. Here

```
while True:
        im = pg.screenshot()
        check = im.getpixel((216, 169))
        time.sleep(1)
        print(check)
```

Now it takes new screenshots every second.

PS - you should keep your imports at the top of the module.